# Force filter on user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made a new Rails project and added Devise for user management. I also made tables like 'posts' and 'tags' and they have a field 'user_id' because the data is per user.
Now I can make queries where I always include user_id as filter. This works fine, but I'm afraid that someday I will forget to filter on user_id and a user can see data of other users.
Is there a way in models to force a certain filter?

For some models like 'posts' and 'tags' I would like to always filter on the current_user. Is there a way to automatically do this or maybe raise an exception if I forget to filter on user?

Any tips are welcome.

(I could use something like Apartment, but I prefer a single database/schema for now)

Comment: Just always start with the user. `current_user.posts.where(...)` instead of `Post.where(user_id: current_user.id, ...)`

Comment: Also something like cancancan will help with owner-based authorization.

Comment: And tests, of course.

Comment: accessible_by in cancancan seems nice. Tests are needed, but I can also make stupid mistakes there :-) current_user.posts.where... is a good idea. Not sure if it works for more complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

In your proxy method for params, you can use the `require` method to require the `user_id` field. Thus if you restrain from using `params` directly, as everybody should, your contraint will be enforced.

Another way is to have a `before_action` filter, where you check your condition. That way, unless you purposefully exclude a method from this filter, your check will always be enforced (or 422 will be returned).

Putting a condition on the model itself seems wrong to me: the model should not know what the access conditions are because access control is an orthogonal feature and should not be entangled with the model.

Comment: A bit of code will help illustrate your point. As it stands, I'm not sure I understand what it is that you're proposing. A `params` check in a `before_action` has nothing to do with what queries the actual action decides to run.

Comment: yeah, on the run, can't do proper code now. params & before_action are separate ways to go.

Comment: doesn't devise already does this? I don't have a problem in the controller.

Comment: ok sorry then, I didn't get your question properly. Then my answer is just the last paragraph: the model should not be trusted with access control in my opinion. It breaks the separation of missions.

Comment: Thus, I trust controllers to be in charge of the access controls - hence my misunderstanding.

Comment: The controller does the access control, but after that it needs to get the correct data. If I forget to filter on the current user the data is wrong.

Comment: yeah sure. So I usually have proxy functions on the controller side (not calling the model static methods directly) and they enforce that the correct calls are made. The controller is responsible for the accesses, including when calling models.